# Football Player auctions

Tags: football, transaction

I was wondering the scenario where a player is playing for a club and is to be transferred (free/purchase) to another club. What is the procedure?

For e.g.,

1. It is the player's wish to go to X Club and he talks to X club's manager
2. It is the Player's manager who takes the decision to move this player for money
   a. He is not playing well
   b. He is getting huge money from the other club for transfer

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer of a player can be initiated as the following situations:

1. Player or Player agent came to team manager with a proposal from another team.
2. Another team or an agent address a team with a proposal to buy player.
3. Player address his manager and ask to be released/sold from the team and if the manager accepts he will put the player in Transfer List (and then the player agent or scouts from another teams will try to find sell deal)
4. Club put player in Transfer List (and then the player agent or scouts from another teams will try to find sell deal)
5. Team want to move the player to another team as part of exchange deal.

In all of those deals the buying club should get to an agreement with the selling club about player price.
Then the buying club should get to an agreement with the player (or his agent) about player contract.
If this is an exchange deal (section 5) the selling club should also get to an agreement with the exchanging player (or his agent) about player contract.

I can think about some reasons for a player move/transfer:

1. Player had finish his contract at the club and both player or team won't want to continue the contract (or not come to an agreement about the details of the new contract).
2. Team want to release/sell the player to another team in order to reduce the wage balance of the team.
3. Team want to sell the player to another team in order to earn money on this player.
4. Team want to release/sell the player to another team נecause of incompetence professionally and \ or personally.
5. Player is asking to move to another team (better challenge, better wage or other reasons) and his current team approved it.
6. Team to sell a player as part of exchange transfer where it can get another player that will suit better for the team

If you can think on some other reasons you can add it to my answer..